# How to restrict date in angular-datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I'm not able to restrict max and min date in angular-datepicker   [angular-datepicker link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datepicker)

```
<div date-picker="start" min-date="Date string | Expression" max-
date="Date string | Expression"></div>
```

What will be valid expression to achieve it?

Below is the list of expression I tried.

1. min-date="2018-03-12 | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
2. min-date="2018-03-12 | 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
3. min-date="2018-03-12 | date"

Comment: The readme on the [Github project](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker) seems to indicate it should just be the date. Have you tried `min-date="2018-03-12"`?

Comment: @Lex It's not working.

Comment: How about `min-date="'2018-03-12'"`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the angular controller for the specific scenario.

**//HTML code**

```
<div date-picker="start" min-date="minDate" max-
date="maxDate"></div>
```

**//Controller code**

```
$scope.minDate = new Date();
$scope.maxDate = new Date(); //as per your expectation
```